# Select tag in android pops out

Tags: android, html, css, select

I have a normal select tag which has some values and makes a drop down list. it is in a webview of my android app. it works as expected in the browser but when I test it in the app and click on it, it pops out in a larger view in the center of the screen. is there any way to prevent it and make it work like in the browser?
Thanks

Comment: are you using jQuery Mobile or Bootstrap for the UI framework

Comment: Yes I'm using jQuery to add option tags